# Accessing/Sending Cookies with NextJS

Tags: next.js, cookies, fastapi

I'm trying to implement some basic auth for a NextJS app.  I have a FastAPI backend which sends a JWT as a cookie on a successful login, which I can see setting the cookie in chrome dev tools, but I can't access this in NextJS.

The FastAPI code for the token request is:

```
@router.post('/users/token')
async def get_token(response: Response, form_data: Annotated[OAuth2PasswordRequestForm, Depends()]):
    print('Token requested')
    if users_collection.find_one({'email': form_data.username}) == None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail='email_not_found')
    try:
        user = authenticate_user(form_data.username, form_data.password)
    except Exception as exception:
        print("exception in get_token calling authenticate user")
        print("get_token exception = " )
        print(exception)
        return exception
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail='incorrect_credentials')
    access_token_expiration_delta = timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    access_token = create_access_token(data={'sub': user.email}, expires_delta=access_token_expiration_delta)
    response.set_cookie(key='access_token', value=access_token, samesite='lax', httponly='true')
    response.status_code = 200
    print('cookie set')
    return response
```

this sets a cookie in chrome:

[image]

However any requests do not send the cookie with the request:

```
'use client'

import { useCookies } from 'next-client-cookies';

// further code...

const clientCookies = useCookies();

async function onSubmit(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    console.log(formData);
    const rawFormData = {
      username: formData.get('username'),
      password: formData.get('password'),
    };
    console.log(rawFormData);

    const response = await fetch(apiAddress + 'users/token', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      credentials: 'include',
    });

    console.log(response.status);
    console.log(typeof response.status);

    if (response.status === 404) {
      handleUserNotFoundOpen();
    }

    if (response.status == 401) {
      console.log('Password incorrect');
      handlePasswordIncorrectOpen();
    }

    if (response.status == 200) {
      console.log('client Cookie:');
      const tokenCookie = clientCookies.get('access_token');
      console.log(tokenCookie); // Returns undefined

      const login_check = await fetch(apiAddress + 'users/get_user/', {
        credentials: 'include',
      });
      console.log(login_check);

      router.push('/dashboard');
    }
```

The get_user endpoint is:

```
@router.get('/users/get_user/')
async def get_user(request: Request):
    print('get current active user called')
    try:
        header = request.headers.get("Cookie")
        print(header)
    except Exception as e:
        print('cookie exception')
        print(e)
    try:
        access_token = request.cookies.get('access_token')
        print('received access token = ' + str(access_token))
        user = await get_current_user(request.cookies.get('access_token'))
        print('user =')
        print(user)
    except Exception as e:
        print('error encountered')
        print(e)
        return {"error": "yes"}
    print("all good")
    return {"Authenticated": "Yes"}
```

CORS (should) be set up to deal with this:

Route FastAPI file:

```
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"]
)
```

Origins include http://localhost:3000

The backend shows no cookie being provided in the request (received access token = None).  Dev tools console also shows no cookie being retrieved.  My understanding is the cookie should be automatically sent with all requests to the backend, but this doesn't seem to be happening.

Requesting the same in POSTMan and then making a GET request to another API endpoint works just fine so I think I am doing something wrong in NextJS.

[image]

Is there a fix for this or is there a simpler way of implementing auth with NextJS?  I'd prefer to use JWT as I plan on implementing middleware to check for valid JWTs for protected routes.

Comment: I was able to fix this by explicitly going to the domain noted instead of just http://localhost; the cookie was set fine